# What does “consume an API” means? With details, please

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api

I would like to know what "consume an API" means in a less technical language possible and would like too some simple example in git and, if possible, using Ruby. I understand that I may be asking a lot, sorry for that, but I can not understand 100% of the examples I found.

I can not go on, because I have not yet been able to fully understand the subject.

Example:

I have a application, a CRUD simple and a API isa JSON that extract the results this CRUD?

Sorry for my limited understanding. I would very much like details with code example, just something basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that you take in data from an external source/url and do something with it. Here is an example:

http://www.theodinproject.com/courses/ruby-programming/lessons/file-i-o-and-serialization